# Sequelize hasMany through another table

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Okay so i have the following three `models`

**Module:**

```
    var Module = sequelize.define('module', {
        id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.STRING,
        category_id: DataTypes.STRING,
        module_type_id: DataTypes.STRING,
        gives_score: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        duration: DataTypes.STRING,
        price: DataTypes.STRING

    }, {
        freezeTableName: true}
)
```

**Competence:**

```
Competence = sequelize.define('competence', {
        id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        organization_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        competence_type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },{freezeTableName:true})
```

**Module_has_competence:**

```
        Module_has_competence = sequelize.define('module_has_competence', {
    id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    module_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    competence_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    score: DataTypes.STRING
},{
    freezeTableName: true}
})
```

As you can see the relation between the tables are an `n:m`

So now i want to find all the `Competence` that a `Module` has:

So i created the following relationship:

```
Module.hasMany(Competence, {through: Module_has_competence, foreignKey: 'module_id'});
```

However when i try to run:

```
  retrieveById: function (quote_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                Module.find({include: [{ all: true }],where: {id: quote_id}})
                    .success(onSuccess).error(onError);
            }
```

it returns nothing. But if i delete the relationship it returns only the `Module`

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

**When i debug**

When i debug it does not log any sql sadly it seems it is just ignoring the sql call ?

Comment: Can you post the SQL queries produced by those statements? Also a state of you DB at that point would be helpful

Comment: @DanRocha Sure hang on please :D

Comment: @DanRocha Sadly it doesnt post any sql :s all my other functions does but this one does not :s

Comment: Are you sure you're  reaching that code? Also try using findAll just to test if theres a problem with find

Comment: @dege the code is reachable because as as soon as i delete the line it collects the modules

Comment: it's weird not posting any sql :/

Comment: try to set {logging: true} on your Sequelize instance

Comment: and as @dege said, try using .findAll({include:[{all: true}]}) or  .findAll({include:[Competence]}) to see if it works

Comment: What version of Sequelize are you using?

Comment: im using version 2.0.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my understanding, the tables you've created a many to many relationship and that when you query for a "Module", you want all the "Competence" associated to it.

Though I wasn't able to get `.hasMany()` working, the error produced was:

```
Trace: [TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined]
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/sjlu/Development/29165644/app.js:61:13)
    at tryCatch1 (/Users/sjlu/Development/29165644/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:45:21)
    at Promise._callHandler (/Users/sjlu/Development/29165644/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:571:13)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/sjlu/Development/29165644/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:581:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/Users/sjlu/Development/29165644/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:713:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/Users/sjlu/Development/29165644/node_modules/sequelize/lib/promise.js:76:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/sjlu/Development/29165644/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:854:14)
    at Async._consumeFunctionBuffer (/Users/sjlu/Development/29165644/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:85:12)
    at Async.consumeFunctionBuffer (/Users/sjlu/Development/29165644/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:40:14)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

In which this output is almost impossible to debug.

However, I was able to create your model bindings and query it correctly with the `.belongsToMany()` associations

```
Competence.belongsToMany(Module, {
    through: Module_has_competence,
    as: 'module',
    foreignKey: 'module_id'
})
Module.belongsToMany(Competence, {
    through: Module_has_competence,
    as: 'competence',
    foreignKey: 'competence_id'
})
```

Which outputs a query that you're looking for

```
  SELECT `module`.`id`, 
         `module`.`name`, 
         `module`.`description`, 
         `module`.`category_id`, 
         `module`.`module_type_id`, 
         `module`.`gives_score`, 
         `module`.`duration`, 
         `module`.`price`, 
         `module`.`createdat`, 
         `module`.`updatedat`, 
         `competence`.`id`                                  AS `competence.id`, 
         `competence`.`name`                                AS `competence.name`, 
         `competence`.`organization_id`                     AS 
         `competence.organization_id`, 
         `competence`.`competence_type_id`                  AS 
         `competence.competence_type_id`, 
         `competence`.`createdat`                           AS 
         `competence.createdAt`, 
         `competence`.`updatedat`                           AS 
         `competence.updatedAt`, 
         `competence.module_has_competence`.`id`            AS 
         `competence.module_has_competence.id`, 
         `competence.module_has_competence`.`module_id`     AS 
         `competence.module_has_competence.module_id`, 
         `competence.module_has_competence`.`competence_id` AS 
         `competence.module_has_competence.competence_id`, 
         `competence.module_has_competence`.`score`         AS 
         `competence.module_has_competence.score`, 
         `competence.module_has_competence`.`createdat`     AS 
         `competence.module_has_competence.createdAt`, 
         `competence.module_has_competence`.`updatedat`     AS 
         `competence.module_has_competence.updatedAt` 
  FROM   `module` AS `module` 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (`module_has_competence` AS 
                         `competence.module_has_competence` 
                          INNER JOIN `competence` AS `competence` 
                                  ON `competence`.`id` = 
  `competence.module_has_competence`.`module_id`) 
  ON `module`.`id` = 
  `competence.module_has_competence`.`competence_id` 
  WHERE  `module`.`id` = 1;
```

To my understanding `.hasMany` references a 1:M relationship, which does not require a join table.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#one-to-many-associations

Here's the gist of how I got to this conclusion:

https://gist.github.com/sjlu/fa5c2e0e267cd692418a

Answer (score 1):

Steven's answer did not work for me but switching the foreign keys.

```
Competence.belongsToMany(Module, {
  through: Module_has_competence,
  as: 'module',
  foreignKey: 'competence_id'
});
Module.belongsToMany(Competence, {
  through: Module_has_competence,
  as: 'competence',
  foreignKey: 'module_id'
});
```