# Sequelize where statement foreign table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following setup:

```
var Module = sequelize.define('module', {
    id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    category_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    module_type_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    gives_score: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    duration: DataTypes.STRING,
    price: DataTypes.STRING

}, {
    freezeTableName: true,})
```

**Organization_has_module**

```
Organization_has_module = sequelize.define('organization_has_module', {
    id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    module_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    organization_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
},{freezeTableName:true});


Module.hasMany(Organization_has_module, {foreignKey: 'module_id'});
```

Now im trying to find all modules where `Organization_has_module.organization_id = 1`

However im not quite sure how to do it

I have the following code:

```
Module.findAll({include: [{ all: true }],where: {module_type_id: type_id}})
.success(onSuccess).error(onError);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the same issue as your other question?

> [Sequelize hasMany through another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165644/sequelize-hasmany-through-another-table/29287044#29287044)

`.hasMany()` doesn't reference a `N:M` relationship, instead it its a `1:M`. You need `.belongsToMany()` to reference a `N:M` due to your join table.

```
Organization.belongsToMany(Module, {
    through: Organization_has_module,
    as: 'module',
    foreignKey: 'module_id'
})
Module.belongsToMany(Organization, {
    through: Organization_has_module,
    as: 'organization',
    foreignKey: 'organization_id'
})
```